# Modeling a one-to many relationship- Model vs ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently trying to model an object class with a one-to-many relationship with another object in Model-First MVC- a "Contact" object that includes, among other things, a list of (references to?) one or more "Interests", chosen upon creation of a Contact from the full database list of Interests. It is my understanding that one uses a ViewModel to accommodate such a relationship, but I think I am misunderstanding what does or does not go in the model vs the viewModel.

At present, I have a Contacts model:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Interest> Interests { get; set; }

    public List<int> InterestIds { get; set; }
}
```

An Interest model:

```
public class Interest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A Contact viewModel:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<int> InterestIds { get; set; }

    public List<InterestViewModel> Interests { get; set; }
}
```

And an Interest viewModel

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<int> InterestIds { get; set; }

    public List<InterestViewModel> Interests { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm getting conflicted accounts of what goes where.

In short, I intend the end result that I should be able to choose one or more Interests (preferably with a series of checkboxes) from the Create view to be stored in the new Contact, and then from the Index view be able to filter the table of Contacts by which Interests they do or do not have. I have logic planned out for most of that already, but for the time being how should I design my Models vs my ViewModels in order to best accommodate this vision?

Comment: In hindsight I am beginning to wonder if I should have used a Many-to-Many relationship instead; I intend for each Contact to have multiple Interests chosen from a list, but while each Interest can be chosen by more than one Contact at the same time, I do not necessarily require an Interest to refer back to all the Contacts that have taken it. What type of relationship would that be?

Answer (score 1):

your `Contact` entity has a logical error, you should remove `InterestIds` property from `Contact` entity and add a property with name `ContactId` to your `Interest` entity. it provides foreign key for contact(one to many relation from `Contact` to `Interest`). however if ViewModel is equals to the Model, so you don't need any ViewModel.

Comment: To be clear my ViewModels being identical to my Models wasn't necessarily a deliberate and necessary design feature; whether or not they should be the same and what if any ways they should differ for their intended purposes was a key part of the question. I was told having ViewModels was beneficial to such operations as having a list of foreign objects to choose from in the creation of the main object; I was hoping someone would elaborate on how to properly design one to that end.