# Do I need a one-to-many or a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, model, many-to-many, one-to-many, rdbms

As a sort of a sequel to or extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584791/modeling-a-one-to-many-relationship-model-vs-viewmodel/53592214#53592214), I am beginning to wonder if perhaps I intended a Many-to-Many relationship between my Contact and Interest models, and would like to try getting a second opinion on the matter.

To summarize or clarify, I have:

**Contact**

- Contains an ID and one or more fields of user contact information (not important to the question)
- Includes a list of one or more Interests associated with that Contact, chosen from a list of Interest objects from the database
- Can choose any number of Interests, up to and including all available Interests, but cannot choose the same Interest more than once.

**Interest**

- Taken from a database-defined list of Interests (would prefer not to hard-code list of options into Model, View, or Controller if possible)
- Exists primarily to provide filtering criteria for the list of Contacts (e.g. "return all Contacts whose Interests include (...)")
- Each Interest can be associated with/chosen by any number of Contacts, but will not necessarily be required to refer back to all associated Contacts in a view

**Required Views**

- Create Contact- Presents user with list of all available Interests, user should be able to choose one or more to be associated with their Contact
- Contact Index- UI includes list of buttons/checkboxes, one for each possible Interest; by selecting one or more of these, the user/administrator may choose to filter which Contacts get returned to the View by whether or not their chosen Interests include one or more of the Interests they specify

Now, I think I have a good enough idea of how to code the logic behind many of these operations; what I *don't* know for certain is whether this would require a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship between the Contact and Interest objects.

I realize I will need another question for the specifics of modelling this properly, but for now which relationship does the above criteria describe: **One-to Many or Many-to-Many?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Many-to-many** would be correct here. You said it yourself: Contacts..."Can choose any number of Interests, up to and including all available Interests", and Interests..."can be associated with/chosen by any number of Contacts". Neither side of the relationship is limited to one association.

Let's say a contact could only choose one interest, but contacts can choose any interest they want regardless of other contacts' choices. This would then be one-to-many, because a contact can only have one interest, but an interest can be associated with many users.